# Error on TestClass using Custom Controller

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller, compile-error

Getting an Error: Constructor not defined: [MyController].(ApexPages.StandardController)

No error when changed to : MyController controller = new MyController();
but getting error on test Class:

Class.MyController.: line 6, column 1

Class.MyController.testMethod1: line 16, column 1

My Test Class

```
@istest
public class MyController{
    static testMethod void testMethod1() 
    {
     Account testAccount = new Account();
     testAccount.Name='Test Account' ;
     insert testAccount;

     Test.StartTest();    
     PageReference pageRef = Page.MyController;
     ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('ParentId', testAccount.id);  
     Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

     **MyController controller = new MyController(new ApexPages.StandardController(testAccount));**

     controller.getAccount();
     controller.getmyfile();
     controller.myfile.name='test';
    controller.myfile.body=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
    controller.Savedoc();  
    PageReference pageRef1 = Page.Confirmation;
   Test.StopTest();
}
```

My Class :

```
   public class MyController {
    private final Account account;
    Public Attachment myfile;

      public MyController() {
        account = [SELECT Id, Name, Site FROM Account 
                   WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    Public Attachment getmyfile()
    {
        myfile = new Attachment();
        return myfile;
    }

    Public Pagereference Savedoc()
    {
        String accid = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('id');
        system.debug('>>>>>AccountId'+accid);
        Attachment a = new Attachment(parentId = accid, name=myfile.name, body = myfile.body);

    try {
        insert a;} 
    catch (DMLException e) {
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading file'));
      system.debug('@@@@Exception'+e);
      return null;
    } 
      PageReference p = Page.Confirmation;
      return p ;
    }   
}
```

My VFP:

```
<apex:page controller="MyController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" tabStyle="Account" >


    <apex:define name="body">  
     <center>
     <apex:panelGrid bgcolor="white" columns="1"> 

       <br/><br/>
          <apex:panelGrid width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="white" columns="1" styleClass="topPanelContainer"> 
              <apex:image id="theImage" value="{!$Resource.Logo}" style="width:200px;height:35px;"/>
           <apex:form >
         <apex:sectionHeader title="Upload your file"/>

     <apex:pageblock >
      <apex:pageblocksection columns="1">
            <apex:outputField value="{!Account.name}"/>
            <apex:inputFile value="{!myfile.body}" fileName="{!myfile.name}"></apex:inputFile>
      <apex:commandbutton value="Submit" action="{!Savedoc}"/>
      </apex:pageblocksection>
     </apex:pageblock>   
     </apex:form> 

               </apex:panelGrid> 
         </apex:panelGrid>
           </center>
    </apex:define>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What error are you getting with running the test class while calling class instance without parameters?

Comment: Would be better to have assert statements whenever you perform a operation to avoid any unexpected result. Like adding assert after account insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because your controller class doesn't have `ApexPages.StandardController` type constructor which you are trying to create in your test class. So either modify your apex class and add one constructor

```
public MyController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
   this.account = (Account)stdController.getRecord();

}
```

and you should use standard controller in your vf page along with extension. 
here is the reference:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your controller to be a custom controller rather than a controller extension. This may be what you intended and is perfectly OK although for Account, not typical

Custom controller constructor signatures look like

```
public MyController() {..}
```

StandardController extension constructor signatures look like

```
public MyController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {..}
```

Your testmethod is trying to use the controller extension constructor signature

```
MyController controller = new MyController(new ApexPages.StandardController(testAccount));
```

If you really want to use a custom controller, then your testmethod needs to do:

```
MyController controller = new MyController();
```

@Himanshu has the answer for standard controller extensions

Comment: @cropedy
Done this : MyController controller = new MyController();
But getting this Error when running the test class:
Class.MyController.: line 6, column 1
Class.MyController.testMethod1: line 16, column 1

Comment: @Smurfet - your comment must have been cut off as that isn't a complete error message. Be sure to edit the OP with latest code